# How to remove white borders on bar charts in highcharts?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

[image]

Here is a picture of the white border that is displayed on bars, can you please help remove the white borders?

Comment: Please provide the minimum code required to reproduce this.

Comment: Grammar and spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the plotOptions.bar.borderWidth to 0 is a solution which you are looking for.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/foapqu40/

```
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.borderWidth

Comment: thanks working for me like series: [{
      borderWidth: 0,
      name: 'Year 1800',
      data: [16, null, 17, 14, 26]
     }, {
      borderWidth: 0,
      name: 'Year 1900',
      data: [6, 44, 23, 36, 6]
     }, {
      borderWidth: 0,
      name: 'Year 2000',
      data: [15, 31, null, 34, 31]
     }, {
      borderWidth: 0,
      name: 'Year 2016',
      data: [56, 12, 43, 12, 7]
     }]

Comment: Yes, you can add it also to series object. In the plotOptions you can set the global options for the chart. Could you accept and vote the answer? ;)